# php mysql; writing data to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

having a bit of trouble adding some data to a database.  I have the file new_entry.php which is a form, which posts the data added to insert_new.php.

Every time the fields are filled in and submitted the data does not go to the database with the error message "Could not add the data to table" appearing..any ideas?

NEW_ENTRY.PHP

```
<body>
 <form method="post" action="insert_new.php"><!-- form sent to insert_new.php-->
  Section: <input type="text" name="section"/><br />
  Food: <input type="text" name="food"/><br />
  Description: <input type="text" name="description"/><br />
  Price: <input type="text" name="price"/><br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

INSERT_NEW.PHP

```
 <?php 
include 'library/connect.php';//connect to databse
$section = $_REQUEST["section"]; // get data from the HTML form on new student form
$food = $_REQUEST["food"];
$description = $_REQUEST["description"];
$price = $_REQUEST["price"];

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO food_menu (section, food, description, price) VALUES ('$section', '$food', '$description', $price)")/* insert the data to the food_menu table*/
    or die ("Could not add the data to table");//error message

header('Location:index.php');//auto redirect to view page
include 'library/closedb.php';
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean $_REQUEST["section"], not $_POST["section"] ?

Comment: Where is `$_REQUEST` defined?

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to SQL injection.  You really should learn to use prepared queries with PDO.

Comment: post your table structure please

Comment: In addition to what others have said, change die("Could not add the data to table") to die(mysql_error()) to get a more useful error message.

Comment: Guys, `$_REQUEST` is like `$_POST` except it takes session, cookie, and get variables as well.

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error()` to get the actual error before the `die`, at least for debugging. Use echo instead of die on unknown output because if the string starts with a number, it doesn't get echoed with die(). Instead, the number is used as the exit value.

Comment: error message back is...Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'

Comment: You might have a non-printable character in your column list. Retype it.

Comment: Thanks Marcus thats seems to of fixed it!

Comment: @DanMcCready - you should have a look at my answer below since your code is unsafe and wide open to SQL injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a mistake at the end of your MySQL query near **price**.

Please replace the code below with existing line:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO food_menu (section, food, description, price) VALUES ('$section', '$food', '$description', '$price')")
```

Tell me the result please.

Comment: This assumes the problem is that the price column is non-numeric; it may be, but more information is needed to make that call.  If it is numeric, and `$price` is numeric data, this is completely legitimate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First:  Don't do this.  You really need to research SQL Injection or you will be very sorry.

Secondly, your price has no numeric validation (assuming it's going into a numeric column)... this is also bad... what if someone put in a dollar sign or something?

Next, please post your table definition and connection code (not the connection values).

You can also get more feedback if you do something like:

```
or die (mysql_error());//error message
```

Comment: it says "Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'" when adding the mysql error message

Comment: Please post your table definition, I think the answer will be forthcoming.